# Puppeteer Find TR with TD That Has Specific Content

Tags: c#, xpath, puppeteer, puppeteer-sharp

I am attempting to click on a row that has a td in in with a specific string in it.

I have attempted this and a few other options:

```
await page.ClickAsync(".//td[contains(., 'ABC-DEF-GHI')]");
```

But i get the error:

```
Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': './/td[contains(., 'ABC-DEF-GHI')]' is not a valid selector.
```

This is what it looks like in a browser:

[image]

Can anyone offer me any advice please?

Comment: Yes! with a small change to var tds = await page.XPathAsync(".//td[contains(., 'ABC-DEF-GHI')]"); await tds[0].ClickAsync(); - THANKS A MILLION!. Please add your answer so i can accept the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use XPath based and not CSS selection use `page.XPathAsync(xpath-expression)` e.g.

```
var tds = page.XPathAsync(".//td[contains(., 'ABC-DEF-GHI')]");
await tds[0].ClickAsync();
```